# Querying wordpress plugin rest API using GraphQL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to implement Smart Slider 3 Wordpress plugin into my Gatsby site. Up until now I've been using "gatsby-source-wordpress" plugin to query wordpress API endpoints using GraphQL. It works fine for posts/pages etc.

However, I am using Smart Slider REST API plugin to query this end point: 
`/wp-json/smartslider3/v1/sliders/<slider-id>`

I can see the response in the browser but I am not sure how to get the results using GraphiQL. Normally I was able to see new endpoints such as "allWordpressPost" etc.

In gatsby-source-wordpress plugin config there are included routes array that needs to be updated to be able to query new endpoints.
Example:

```
"**/categories",
"**/posts",
"**/pages",
"**/media",
```

Therefore I've added this one `"**/sliders",` but seems like I can't get results to show in GraphiQL.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways I think you could do what you want:

1. Query it directly client-side, ex. using `window.fetch` or [`wpapi`](https://github.com/wp-api/node-wpapi)
2. Fork `gatsby-source-wordpress` and add in support for it yourself

By default, `gatsby-source-wordpress` supports the following plugins:

- Custom Post Types, including those made with Custom Post Type UI WordPress plugin
- Advanced Custom Fields + ACF to REST API
- WP API MENUS
- WPML REST API
- WP REST Polylang
- Yoast + WP API Yoast Meta

See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/#wordpress-plugins

So while you can include or exclude routes like `comments` or `media`, adding a route for other plugin APIs isn’t enough to make it work.

Similar to you, I ended up needing support for Gravity Forms, and forked `gatsby-source-wordpress` and added support for it myself. It’s doable and doesn’t necessarily require a huge amount of changes to the original plugin, but it is one more thing to maintain.

To try and deal with this in the future, I wrote up a proposal for adding a generic way to do this, so it would be possible to do exactly what you are after without needing to modify `gatsby-source-wordpress`. If you wouldn’t mind explaining what you are looking to do there too, it might help make it something that can be pursued in the future.

- Proposal https://github.com/kennethormandy/gatsby-rfcs/blob/wordpress-source-plugins/text/0000-wordpress-source-plugins.md
- GitHub Issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/rfcs/pull/23

In the short-term, the above options are what’s available.